# How to set variables based on project id?

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I currently have an App Engine Go app with 2 projects: `myapp-prod` and `myapp-staging`.

I'd like to be able to set the value of certain variables depending if the app is running in prod or staging.

Is there a way for the app to detect which environment it is running in?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an [environment variable](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/config/appconfig#Go_app_yaml_Defining_environment_variables) describing whether your app is on production or staging. Add to `app.yml`,

```
env_variables:
  ENVIRONMENT: 'production'
```

In your code,

```
import "os"

if v := os.Getenv("ENVIRONMENT"); v == "production" {
  // You're in production
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to set the environment variable from the command line instead of in app.yml? Otherwise there's not really a good way to know if my app is running in project 'myapp-prod' or 'myapp-staging'

Comment: Noting here that `appcfg.py` offers the following argument options: -E NAME:VALUE, --env_variable=NAME:VALUE
                        Set an environment variable, potentially overriding an
                        env_variable value from app.yaml file (flag may be
                        repeated to set multiple variables).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `appengine.AppID()` function to get the name/id of your application:

```
// AppID returns the application ID for the current application.
// The string will be a plain application ID (e.g. "appid"), with a
// domain prefix for custom domain deployments (e.g. "example.com:appid"). 
func AppID(c Context) string
```

And you can use `appengine.IsDevAppServer()` to tell if your app is running in development mode (using the AppEngine SDK) or live (in production):

```
// IsDevAppServer reports whether the App Engine app is running in the
// development App Server. 
func IsDevAppServer() bool
```

Alternatively you can also use `appengine.ServerSoftware()` which contains both of the information above, merged into one string:

```
// ServerSoftware returns the App Engine release version.
// In production, it looks like "Google App Engine/X.Y.Z".
// In the development appserver, it looks like "Development/X.Y". 
func ServerSoftware() string
```

Comment: Thanks Ill try AppID(). IsDevAppServer() wont work in this case because im trying to differentiate running on different projects `myapp-prod` and `myapp-staging` neither of which are running in dev model.

Comment: @sthomps Yeah, I know, I mentioned it because it is relevant and might be useful for someone else.