# How to differentiate between local deployment and live deployment on Google AppEngine

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I want to set global variable, for example:

```
var DEBUG_MODE bool

func init() {
  // set DEBUG_MODE true if localhost (not appspot.com or other domain)
}
```

How to do this?

Comment: which programming language do you use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest is to use use [`appengine.IsDevAppServer()`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/reference#IsDevAppServer) to tell if your app is running in development mode (using the AppEngine SDK) or live (in production):

> ```
> func IsDevAppServer() bool
> ```
>
> IsDevAppServer reports whether the App Engine app is running in the development App Server.

Alternatively you can also use [`appengine.ServerSoftware()`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/reference#ServerSoftware) which contains this information along with your App version, merged into one string:

> ```
> func ServerSoftware() string
> ```
>
> ServerSoftware returns the App Engine release version. In production, it looks like "Google App Engine/X.Y.Z". In the development appserver, it looks like "Development/X.Y".

So for example what you want to do:

```
var DEBUG_MODE bool

func init() {
    DEBUG_MODE = appengine.IsDevAppServer()
}
```

Or in one line:

```
var DEBUG_MODE = appengine.IsDevAppServer()
```

Although note that you could just call `appengine.IsDevAppServer()` whenever you would refer to `DEBUG_MODE`. Also the name `DEBUG_MODE` does not conform to Go naming conventions, it should either be `DebugMode` if it needs to be exported (because you want to access it from other packages too), or it should be `debugMode` if it doesn't need to be exported.

See this related question (possible duplicate?): [How to set variables based on project id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36184603/how-to-set-variables-based-on-project-id)